# NSDateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate returning nil in iOS 8.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, nsdateformatter, ios8.3

I have this code

```
NSString *stringDate = @"2015-07-09 7:00 AM";
NSString *stringDateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a";
NSTimeZone *timeZone =  [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:stringDateFormat];
NSDate *dateFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

The problem now is *dateFormatted* keeps getting nil value. It is OK when I try it in Simulator iPhone5s 8.2 but, the problem occurs when I run it with device iPhone5s 8.3.

Can someone help me find why is *dateFormatted* is getting nil value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost a canned response but: [QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). Set your formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX` or its behaviour will be dependent upon the user's settings.

Comment: The link you provided explained what is really happening and why it is failing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, it's a little obscure but my understanding is: if `NSDateFormatter` is taking the user's locale into account then it reserves the right to tweak date formats. It will take the user's locale into account by default. You can set that specific locale to disable that. At a guess: Apple wanted people to get display dates right by default because any mistakes there probably don't show up on bug trackers but will annoy people, but have to do some work to get internet dates correct, because any mistakes there probably do show up on bug trackers.

Comment: The link is really helpful!